# Component not re-rendering when using async dispatch in a button press button

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

So, I implemented redux with thunk using the guide included in the site:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

The action I'm using looks like this:

```
export const addDemoData = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/demo',
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      return await doAddDemoData();
    } catch (err) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue((err.response && err.response.data) || {code: 'INTERNAL', message: err.message});
    }
  }
)
```

The slice that handle this action looks like this:

```
export const authSlice  = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
   
  },
  // async action
  extraReducers: {
    [addDemoData.pending]: (state) => {
  // Add user to the state array
  state.loading = 'loading';
  state.error = null; // clears the error
},
    [addDemoData.fulfilled]: (state) => {
      state.loading = 'idle';
    },
    [addDemoData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
  state.loading = 'error';
  state.error = action.payload;
}    
  }
})
```

The main component that calls the dispatch looks like this. Before calling the dispatch I set the button color to green, and when it's finished to yellow:

```
  const {loading} = useAppSelector(state => state.auth)
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [color, setColor] = useState('yellow');

  const isLoading = loading === 'loading';
  console.log('isLoading', isLoading, color);

  const doAddDemoDataPress =  () => { 
    setColor('green');    
    dispatch(addDemoData())
      .then(unwrapResult)
      .then(originalPromiseResult => {
        setColor('yellow');
        console.log("originalPromiseResult", originalPromiseResult)
      })
      .catch(rejectedValueOrSerializedError => console.log("originalPromiseResult", rejectedValueOrSerializedError));
  }

...

<Spacer>
  <Button color={color} title={`PRESS ME`} onPress={doAddDemoDataPress} />
</Spacer>
```

If you see the logs, you can see isLoading and the color changing. The button should appear at least 7 seconds with color green:

```
[Thu Mar 11 2021 01:25:37.512]  LOG      isLoading true green
[Thu Mar 11 2021 01:25:37.567]  LOG      adding demo data....
[Thu Mar 11 2021 01:25:44.925]  LOG      isLoading true green
[Thu Mar 11 2021 01:25:44.971]  LOG      isLoading true green
[Thu Mar 11 2021 01:25:45.400]  LOG      isLoading false yellow
[Thu Mar 11 2021 01:25:45.390]  LOG      originalPromiseResult undefined
```

But I only see the button pressed (dark yellow) all that time the task is running and then goes back to yellow again. Never goes green.
The dispatch returns a promise correctly, and is also handled correctly. But I don't see any redraw of the component during all that period of time.

Now, If I replace the  doAddDemoDataPress to something like this:

```
  const doAddDemoDataPress =  () => {
    setColor('green');
    setTimeout(function () {
      setColor('yellow')
    }, 1000);
  }
```

the logs also shows the values changing correctly:

```
[Thu Mar 11 2021 01:30:41.472]  LOG      isLoading false green
[Thu Mar 11 2021 01:30:42.493]  LOG      isLoading false yellow
```

In this case I see the button turning green for those 2 seconds and the going yellow again.

What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

**edit**

To add more, doAddDemoData is just an async method that writes in a realm(local) database:

```
export const doAddDemoData = async () => {
  const realm = await getRealm();  
  realm.write(() => {
```

What is stranger is that if I add an setTimeout before this action the re-rendering happens!

```
export const addDemoData = createAsyncThunk(
    'auth/demo',
    async (_, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1));
            return await doAddDemoData();
        } catch (err) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue((err.response && err.response.data) || {
                code: 'INTERNAL',
                message: err.message
            });
        }
    }
)
```

Could it be that those Realm writes are to heavy(hdd work) that actually freeze the rendering?

Comment: What is `doAddDemoData` in return `await doAddDemoData();`?

Comment: Well, Redux has no control over whether React rerenders independently of it - and also, it seems to do so as otherwise you wouldn't be getting those `console.log` calls at all. So it's a bit of a mystery, but I'd rather search that in your rendering logic (like, the button component for example or maybe you have a shadowed `color` variable somewhere).

Since you skipped most of that, it's pretty much impossible to say anything about that.

Comment: I expanded the information... adding a setTimeOut before the task actually calls the re-rendering.. that some weird behavior

Comment: it seems that realm has some ui blocking issues ... maybe it is that https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/836